# html_select_time select boxes with white space between them

Tags: smarty

When I use `{html_select_time}` it shows the select boxes for time, but there is a white space between them.

I know that select boxes have to really next to eachother without enters or spaces, but how can I do that here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for Smarty V2 you can use negative margin,
for Smarty V3 you might try `field_separator=""` attribute
( http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.html.select.time.tpl )